# Saving Record in Relation Spring Boot

Tags: java, jpa, spring-boot

I am creating a project in spring boot which creates record by api call.
so I have two table ( name and phone ) below is my domain:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "name")
public class Name {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
private Long id;

@Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
private String name;

@Column(name = "active", nullable = false)
private boolean active = true;

@LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "name")
@JsonIgnoreProperties("name")
private List<Phone> phones;
}
```

And

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "phone")
public class Phone {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
private Long id;

@Column(name = "number", nullable = false)
private String number;

@Column(name = "active", nullable = false)
private boolean active = true;

@ManyToOne(targetEntity= Name.class)
@JoinColumn(name="name_id"))
private Name name;
}
```

The Code to create the name is as follows:

```
public Name createNewName(Name createName) {
    Name newName = new Name();
    newName = NameRepo.save(createName);
    return newName;
}
```

And Repository is:

```
@Repository
public interface NameRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Name, Long>     {}
```

So My problem is when i send a request using api to call this, Name does not store Phone values and also does not link if exist.

My request is as follows:

```
{
"name": "testrretf",
"active": true,
"phones":[{
    "id":1
}]
```

}

This request should link the new Name to existing Phone id=1
And

```
 {
"name": "testrretf",
"active": true,
"phones":[{
    "number":"Test Phone",
    "active":true,
}]
```

}

This request should create a Phone and link to the created Name.

Please help me..

Thanks,

UPDATE# Below is the Create Table Query:

```
CREATE TABLE `name` (
`id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`active` bit(1) NOT NULL,
`name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 UNIQUE KEY `IDX_NAME` (`name `),
 KEY `IDX_NAME_ACTIVE` (`active`)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1



CREATE TABLE `phone` (
`id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`active` bit(1) NOT NULL,
`name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`name_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 KEY `IDX_PHONE_ACTIVE` (`active`),
 KEY `fk_name_phone` (`name_id`),
 CONSTRAINT `fk_name_phone` FOREIGN KEY (`name_id`) REFERENCES `name` (`id`)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Comment: As a starter for one you are missing the `@Entity` annotation on your tables.

Comment: @PaulNUK, I missed that part, i already have entity, everything is good except the saving of one to many relation.

Comment: OK next one, you've no IDs on either table

Comment: You put `@JoinColumn(name="name_id"))` but I don't see ids on both entities...also try to post the `CREATE TABLE` statement from both table so we have a clear picture.

Comment: Hi @dierre, added create table query